# How to debug the error "unexpected char CS1056"?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I'm trying to compile but not work

```
  using System;

  using System.IO;

  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;




class Program


     {

   static void Main()

      {

    string strFile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebaregex2.txt"); 

 strFile = Regex.Replace(strFile, @"((FA|BO)\\s+(\\d{3}-\\d+)(\\s+)(.*?)(\\s+)(\\d+,*\\d*\\.\\d+)\\s*(FA|BO)\\s+(\\d{3}-\\d+)(\\s+)(.*?)(\\s+)(\\d+,*\\d*\.\\d+)\\s*, @"$2&$4&$6\\n$8&$10&$12");

  File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\pruebaregex2.txt", strFile);

  }
}
```

I have tried to correct it but not know how to fix this error

In this part appears the error

```
"$2&$4&$6\\n$8&$10&$12"

Error CS1056: Character '$' unexpected
```

Comment: Even basic syntax highlighting on SO points to the same problem... You may want to put closing quote at the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing a closing quote after `\\s*` the second argument in the `Replace` call.

```
strFile = Regex.Replace(
    strFile, 
    @"((FA|BO)\\s+(\\d{3}-\\d+)(\\s+)(.*?)(\\s+)(\\d+,*\\d*\\.\\d+)\\s*(FA|BO)\\s+(\\d{3}-\\d+)(\\s+)(.*?)(\\s+)(\\d+,*\\d*\.\\d+)\\s*",
    @"$2&$4&$6\\n$8&$10&$12");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the double quotes here 
`@"$2&$4&$6\\n$8&$10&$12");`

just duplicate it to be 
`@""$2&$4&$6\\n$8&$10&$12");`

in case you don't need it, just remove it